# flink HA standalone cluster failed

Tags: akka, cluster-computing, apache-flink, high-availability

2 computers，203，204 
both run `jobmanager` and `taskmanager` on every computer

masters

```
hz203:9081
hz204:9081
```

slaves

```
hz203
hz204
```

flink-conf.yaml

```
jobmanager.rpc.port: 6123
rest.port: 9081
blob.server.port: 6124
query.server.port: 6125
web.tmpdir: /home/ctu/flink/deploy/webTmp
web.log.path: /home/ctu/flink/deploy/log
taskmanager.tmp.dirs: /home/ctu/flink/deploy/taskManagerTmp
high-availability: zookeeper
high-availability.storageDir: file:///home/ctu/flink/deploy/HA
high-availability.zookeeper.quorum: 10.0.1.79:2181
high-availability.zookeeper.path.root: /flink
high-availability.cluster-id: /flink
```

run `./start-cluster.sh`

```
Starting HA cluster with 2 masters.
Starting standalonesession daemon on host hz203.
Starting standalonesession daemon on host hz204.
Starting taskexecutor daemon on host hz203.
Starting taskexecutor daemon on host hz204.
```

logs

```
2018-12-20 20:44:03,843 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.leaderelection.ZooKeeperLeaderElectionService  - Starting ZooKeeperLeaderElectionService ZooKeeperLeaderElectionService{leaderPath='/leader/rest_server_lock'}.
2018-12-20 20:44:03,864 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.dispatcher.DispatcherRestEndpoint    - Web frontend listening at http://127.0.0.1:9081.
2018-12-20 20:44:03,875 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcService              - Starting RPC endpoint for org.apache.flink.runtime.resourcemanager.StandaloneResourceManager at akka://flink/user/resourcemanager .
2018-12-20 20:44:03,989 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcService              - Starting RPC endpoint for org.apache.flink.runtime.dispatcher.StandaloneDispatcher at akka://flink/user/dispatcher .
2018-12-20 20:44:03,999 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.leaderelection.ZooKeeperLeaderElectionService  - Starting ZooKeeperLeaderElectionService ZooKeeperLeaderElectionService{leaderPath='/leader/resource_manager_lock'}.
2018-12-20 20:44:04,008 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.leaderretrieval.ZooKeeperLeaderRetrievalService  - Starting ZooKeeperLeaderRetrievalService /leader/resource_manager_lock.
2018-12-20 20:44:04,009 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.leaderelection.ZooKeeperLeaderElectionService  - Starting ZooKeeperLeaderElectionService ZooKeeperLeaderElectionService{leaderPath='/leader/dispatcher_lock'}.
2018-12-20 20:44:04,010 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.leaderretrieval.ZooKeeperLeaderRetrievalService  - Starting ZooKeeperLeaderRetrievalService /leader/dispatcher_lock.
2018-12-20 20:44:04,206 WARN  akka.remote.transport.netty.NettyTransport                    - Remote connection to [null] failed with java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: /127.0.0.1:43012
2018-12-20 20:44:04,221 WARN  akka.remote.ReliableDeliverySupervisor                        - Association with remote system [akka.tcp://flink@127.0.0.1:43012] has failed, address is now gated for [50] ms. Reason: [Association failed with [akka.tcp://flink@127.0.0.1:43012]] Caused by: [Connection refused: /127.0.0.1:43012]
2018-12-20 20:44:04,301 WARN  akka.remote.transport.netty.NettyTransport                    - Remote connection to [null] failed with java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: /127.0.0.1:43012
2018-12-20 20:44:04,301 WARN  akka.remote.ReliableDeliverySupervisor                        - Association with remote system [akka.tcp://flink@127.0.0.1:43012] has failed, address is now gated for [50] ms. Reason: [Association failed with [akka.tcp://flink@127.0.0.1:43012]] Caused by: [Connection refused: /127.0.0.1:43012]
2018-12-20 20:44:04,378 WARN  akka.remote.transport.netty.NettyTransport                    - Remote connection to [null] failed with java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: /127.0.0.1:43012
2018-12-20 20:44:04,378 WARN  akka.remote.ReliableDeliverySupervisor                        - Association with remote system [akka.tcp://flink@127.0.0.1:43012] has failed, address is now gated for [50] ms. Reason: [Association failed with [akka.tcp://flink@127.0.0.1:43012]] Caused by: [Connection refused: /127.0.0.1:43012]
2018-12-20 20:44:04,451 WARN  akka.remote.transport.netty.NettyTransport                    - Remote connection to [null] failed with java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: /127.0.0.1:43012
2018-12-20 20:44:04,451 WARN  akka.remote.ReliableDeliverySupervisor                        - Association with remote system [akka.tcp://flink@127.0.0.1:43012] has failed, address is now gated for [50] ms. Reason: [Association failed with [akka.tcp://flink@127.0.0.1:43012]] Caused by: [Connection refused: /127.0.0.1:43012]
2018-12-20 20:44:04,520 WARN  akka.remote.transport.netty.NettyTransport                    - Remote connection to [null] failed with java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: /127.0.0.1:43012
```

questions

```
`akka.tcp://flink@127.0.0.1:33567/user/resourcemanager` --- Why the 127.0.0.1 instead of the `jobmanager` ip in the `masters's` config file?
```

Comment: Which version of Flink are you using? Would it be possible to share the full logs with us?

Comment: version: flink-1.6.0, full logs has been sent to your xxxx@apache.org mailbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is a bug we fixed in version `1.6.1`. In `1.6.0` we did not respect the `--host` command line option in the method `ClusterEntrypoint#loadConfiguration` as you can see [here](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/release-1.6.0/flink-runtime/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/runtime/entrypoint/ClusterEntrypoint.java#L698) compared to the [code of version 1.6.1](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/release-1.6.1/flink-runtime/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/runtime/entrypoint/ClusterEntrypoint.java#L698).

Thus, upgrading to the latest 1.6.x version should fix the problem. In general I would always recommend upgrading to the latest bug fix version of a release if possible.